# Printing month name from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Am trying to print `month_name` from the list but am getting the `list` by using this `calendar module` but i received this error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

but when i convert the `list` to `integer` is still doesn't solve the problem.

How can i print the month name from the month.

```
import calendar


month_value = ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]

print(month_value)

bn = calendar.month_name[month_value]

print(bn)
```

Comment: You converted that list to an integer? What integer did you convert it to?

Comment: You probably meant `bn = calendar.month_name[month_value[0]]` or something.

Comment: the element in the list is string `"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"` sorry for the mistake .Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to creat a new list of month names. `month_name` expect a single integer value to resolve it to a month name and you are passing the entire list or may be a part of the list.

```
import calendar
month_value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]  
print(month_value)

bn = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in month_value]

print(bn)
```

Output:

```
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Or you just need the name_list then use range(1,13)

```
bn = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1,13)]
```

or just use slice

```
bn = calendar.month_name[1:13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over your month_value array. (e.g. with a for loop, or inline)

```
import calendar

month_value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
print(month_value)

bn = []
for month in month_value:
    bn.append(calendar.month_name[month])

print(bn)
```

Output:

```
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `month_name` receives as a parameter an integer, not a list as you did.

if you would like to print all month names, I suggest:

```
import calendar
month_value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for month_number in month_value:
    print(calendar.month_name[month_number])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call that in one of those ways:

```
import calendar

print(calendar.month_name[6:9])   # ['June', 'July', 'August']
print(calendar.month_name[3])     # 'March'

# this is the list of month names:
bn = calendar.month_name[1:13]
```

see the [`calendar` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html?highlight=calendar#calendar.month_name).

the argument can either be an index or a slice. you are passing a whole list to it...

Answer (score -2):

In bash scripting is like this:

```
 echo "Write a number from 1 - 12: "
    read "$month"
    case ("$month$") in 
    1) echo "January";;
    2) echo "February";;
    3) echo "March";;
    ...
    12) echo "December";;
    *) echo "Invalid number."
       exit 1;;
    exit 0`
```

Comment: Not my downvote but it doesnot seems to be written in Python as expected by OP